# Delete artifacts from nexus repo via task script

Tags: groovy, nexus, sonatype, nexus3

Currently, i am using `nexus 3.2 Community  edition,`

is there any way we can create a task in nexus to delete artefacts that were uploaded in nexus 365 days ( or a custom date) from the maven-release repo in nexus

I could see there is the option to create a script task based on groovy  I have no idea about groovy

can I get a help on it

[image]

Comment: You are running a very old version of nexus3 subject to several security issues which have been fixed. The newest version also comes with new and enhanced features, amongst which [cleanup policies](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/repository-management/cleanup-policies) which I believe should help in your case. If not, writing groovy scripts requires development skills. Sonatype provides some [base examples](https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-scripting-examples). In the newest version, you will also find an API menu in the admin that can help you achieve the same goal.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. yes I,  have upgraded to 3.30 since didn't find a way to remove old artefacts and it working fine with the cleanup policy and task.